# TfrxRichView do FastReport mudando a cor sozinho no Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, fast-reports

Procurei na web mas não encontrei nada nesse sentido, deve ter algum bug no componente `TfrxRichView` do [FastReport 5.1.9](http://www.fast-report.com/pt/), ao colocar esse componente e setar a cor de fundo ele aceita normal, mas quando manda imprimir em tempo de desenvolvimento ele simplesmente fica com fundo branco (padrão) e mais, ele mesmo retira a seleção de cor do componente, isso também ocorre em tempo de execução.

Mesmo forçando mudar a cor no `OnBeforePrint` ele ignora, alguém já passou por isso e teve uma solução?

O cenário é Delphi XE com FastReport 5.1.9

Comment: Compilado para Mobile ou Descktop?

Comment: Desktop, pensei que pode ser uma limitação do TfrxRichView já que ele aceita formatação de texto, mas ai não faria sentido essa propriedade estar la

Answer (score 1):

**Veja se a formatação da sua cor está correta:**

Antes de tudo cheque se o valor aceito pela cor deve ser no formato `hexadecimal`, `TAlphaColor` ou `RGB`.
Você pode fazer isso salvando o arquivo com essa propriedade, abrindo o arquivo gerado com final `fr3` e analisando o texto após a tag `<Color>`, daí já da pra ver o formato esperado de cor.

---

Além disso vejo 2 maneiras de você resolver isso:

**1ª Maneira**

- Faça todas as alterações estáticas que você quer e salve o view como um arquivo `FR3`.
- No Form que você quer usar o report coloque um componente `TfrxReport` em branco.
- Quando você for  ativar a view desse report utilize `NomeDoReport.LoadFromFile(Caminho + NomeDoReport.fr3);`
- Mostre o View com `NomeDoReport.Show;`

**2ª Maneira**

- Deixe o Report já preparado ou carregue ele como no 3º passo da 1ª maneira
- Declare uma variável `TfrxMemoView` no código do seu Form
- Atribua as propriedades do objeto desejado a essa variável através do código: `NomeDoMeuMemoView := NomeDoReport.FindObject('NomeDoObjetoDesejado') as TfrxMemoView;`
- Acesse as propriedades desejadas usando `NomeDoMeuView.NomeDaPropriedade := 'ValorNovo';`
- Quando mudar tudo que deseja Prepare o Report `NomeDoReport.PrepareReport;`
- Mostre o relatório preparado em runtime com `NomeDoReport.ShowPreparedReport;`

---

**Exemplo da 1ª Maneira:**

```
[...] //cabeçalho do Delphi e outras variáveis
ExemploReport: TfrxReport;
[...] //implementation, outras procedures e functions
procedure TfmxForm1.MostraReportCarregado;
begin
ExemploReport.LoadFromFile(Caminho + 'ExemploReport.fr3');
ExemploReport.Show;
end;
```

**Exemplo da 2ª Maneira:**

```
[...] //cabeçalho do Delphi e outras variáveis
ExemploReport: TfrxReport;
ObjetoExemploReport: TfrxMemoView;
[...] //implementation, outras procedures e functions
procedure TfmxForm1.MudaCabeçalhoReport;
begin
ExemploReport.PrepareReport(True); //aqui estou preparando o report para edição
RadiusReport.LoadFromFile(Caminho + 'ExemploReport.fr3');
ObjetoExemploReport := ExemploReport.FindObject('NomeDoObjeto') as TfrxMemoView;
ObjetoExemploReport.Text := 'Texto Mudado';
ExemploReport.PrepareReport;
ExemploReport.ShowPreparedReport;
end;
```

---

**Considerações**

A 1ª maneira é mais fácil de implementar no seu sistema, porém fica amarrada a valores estáticos, uma ótima alternativa se quer evitar erros e quer uma implementação rápida, porém a 2ª maneira muda as propriedades em runtime, ou seja, abre espaço para possibilidades de customização pelo usuário do sistema.

Comment: Considerando esta parte "valor aceito pela cor deve ser no formato hexadecimal", o valor da cor vem do combo do próprio componente, desta forma não tem como estar errado, salvo algum bug.

Comment: Considerando os exemplos, vou fazer a alterações ver os resultados e posto aqui.